# Kotlin: userNameRealmPasswordDigestProvider Deprecated Error

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I have created new Ktor application via Ktor plugin for IntelliJ Idea. Without any change in any file of the project, I have this error:

Using 'userNameRealmPasswordDigestProvider: suspend (userName: String, realm: String) -> ByteArray?' is an error. Use digestProvider { } function instead.

for this part of Application.kt file:

```
digest("myDigestAuth") {
            userNameRealmPasswordDigestProvider = { userName, realm ->
                usersInMyRealmToHA1[userName]
            }
        }
```

Could anyone help how to fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To fix it just pass the same lambda to the `digestProvider` method:

```
digest("myDigestAuth") {
    digestProvider { userName, realm ->
        usersInMyRealmToHA1[userName]
    }
}
```